# gtest/Google Test C++ build error on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, testing, googletest, build-error

I am trying to build a simple test using gtest on the latest version of Visual Studio 2017. The code is the following:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct BankAccount
{
    int balance = 0;

    BankAccount()
    {
    }

    explicit BankAccount(const int balance)
        : balance{ balance }
    {
    }
};

TEST(AccountTest, BankAccountStartsEmpty)
{
    BankAccount account;
    EXPECT_EQ(0, account.balance);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

And the build error is:

```
 Error  C4996   'std::tr1': warning STL4002: The non-Standard std::tr1 namespace and TR1-only machinery are deprecated and will be REMOVED. 
You can define _SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING to acknowledge that you have received this warning.
```

I already tried:

```
#define _SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING
```

But it just makes things worse. 
I dont know how to fix this error.

**UPDATE**

I tried adding the define in the preprocessor's definitions and above the includes. Neither works!!

Comment: where did you put the `#define` command?

Comment: Above the includes at first, and then in the preprocessor definition's settings. Neither worked.

Comment: I recommend getting GTest working *without precompiled headers*.  This will remove one set of possible issues.  You can always turn on PCH after you get Google Test working.

Comment: Is that version of gtest available for download through NuGet packages? Or should I find it elsewhere?

Comment: I'm almost sure I've seen something about `tr1` problems somewhere in Googletest docs, but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Or not, it was about using your own `tr1` tuple library together with GoogleTest. It was removed from readme in September 2018. [It doesn't look helpful](https://github.com/google/googletest/commit/5c89346def29d97e6b40cc462106659d0a9ef9d7#diff-a8bd9c0a0a6f1596f1c9cdcc5a7fd294)

Answer (score 0):

Try going to:

> View -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor

and Set Preprocessor Definitions as `_SILENCE_TR1_NAMESPACE_DEPRECATION_WARNING`

Also another solution is to re-enable `TR1` by defining `_HAS_TR1_NAMESPACE`.

However, disabling error is not a good idea. Your warning may be present due to incorrect project setting and you should inform `gtest` that your compiler version supports
newer C++ versions by setting `GTEST_LANG_CXX11` to be `1`.